# Shiny app output show in console but not in main panel

Tags: r, vector, shiny, output, shinyapps

I'm creating a Shiny app where the user can go through and select different lines from various poems to generate a new sonnet. However, when I run the app, my output is not appearing in the app and will only show up in the console. What am I missing here?

```
library(shiny) 
library(tidyverse)
Sonnets <- read_csv("https://blades.byu.edu/hon290/hon290cofwsonnets2021.text")
mylines <- c()
library(english)
Vector <- function(mylines) {
for(i in 1:14) {
Sonnets %>%
filter(sonnet==mylines[i]& line==i) %>%
select(text) %>%
print()
}
}
server = function(input, output) (
output$q <- renderText({
paste(vector(c(input$line1, input$line2, input$line3, input$line4, input$line5, input$line6, input$line7, input$line8, input$line9, input$line10, input$line11, input$line12, input$line13, input$14)))
})
)

ui<- fluidPage(
titlePanel("City of Women Sonnets"), 
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("Sonnet Generator By Line",
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
h3("Build Your Poem",
fluidRow(
                  column(6, numericInput("line1", "Line 1", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line2", "Line 2", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line3", "Line 3", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line4", "Line 4", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line5", "Line 5", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line6", "Line 6", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line7", "Line 7", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line8", "Line 8", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line9", "Line 9", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line10", "Line 10", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line11", "Line 11", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line12", "Line 12", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line13", "Line 13", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                  column(6, numericInput("line14", "Line 14", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                ))
           ),
           mainPanel(h3("poem"),
                     textOutput("q"))
         ))
)
)
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I genuinely don't know much about coding, I'm just taking a class (for fun) that includes basic coding and I'm a little lost on what to at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Running your above code I got the following error:

> Error in source("~/.active-rstudio-document", echo = TRUE) :
> ~/.active-rstudio-document:49:192: unexpected numeric constant 48:
> output$q <- renderText({ 49:     paste(c(input$line1, input$line2,
> input$line3, input$line4, input$line5, input$line6, input$line7,
> input$line8, input$line9, input$line10, input$line11, input$line12,
> input$line13, input$14

This is caused by a typo in your `renderText` call (`input$14` instead of `input$line14`).

Try running the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
# library(tidyverse)
# library(english)

# Sonnets <- read_csv("https://blades.byu.edu/hon290/hon290cofwsonnets2021.text")
mylines <- c()

Vector <- function(mylines) {
  for(i in 1:14) {
    Sonnets %>%
      filter(sonnet==mylines[i]& line==i) %>%
      select(text) %>%
      print()
  }
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("City of Women Sonnets"), 
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Sonnet Generator By Line",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 h3("Build Your Poem",
                    fluidRow(
                      column(6, numericInput("line1", "Line 1", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line2", "Line 2", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line3", "Line 3", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line4", "Line 4", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line5", "Line 5", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line6", "Line 6", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line7", "Line 7", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line8", "Line 8", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line9", "Line 9", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line10", "Line 10", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line11", "Line 11", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line12", "Line 12", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line13", "Line 13", min=1, max=23, value=1)),
                      column(6, numericInput("line14", "Line 14", min=1, max=23, value=1))
                    ))
               ),
               mainPanel(h3("poem"),
                         uiOutput("q"))
             ))
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) (
  output$q <- renderUI({
    HTML(paste(input$line1, input$line2, input$line3, input$line4, input$line5, input$line6, input$line7, input$line8, input$line9, input$line10, input$line11, input$line12, input$line13, input$line14, sep = "<br>"))
  })
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```